# How to update progressview in uitableviewcell (Multiple download file)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, upload

I'm editing from upload file (upload multiple it's working fine.)

upload file from

[How to update progressview in uitableview cell by urlsession (download/upload file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60200140/how-to-update-progressview-in-uitableview-cell-by-urlsession-download-upload-fi)

but change to download file progressview not update in cell. ??

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    var url : URL?
    var DestFolder : String?
    var dataArr : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray.init()
      var dataArrDone : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray.init()

      var myTableview:UITableView = UITableView.init()
      let color = UIColor(red: 69/255, green: 57/255, blue: 169/255, alpha: 1.0)
      let cellID: String = "customCell"
    var downloadTasks: [URLSessionDownloadTask : IndexPath] = [:]



    func viewTag(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> Int {
              return indexPath.row + 1000
          }


   override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
       // Change font of status bar is white.
       .lightContent

   }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

                   dataArr=["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg"]
                   dataArrDone=["wait","wait","wait","wait"]



                   //print(dataArr)
                   let myScreen = UIScreen.main.bounds
                   let statusHieght = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height

                   if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                       let app = UIApplication.shared
                       let statusBarHeight: CGFloat = app.statusBarFrame.size.height

                       let statusbarView = UIView()
                       statusbarView.backgroundColor = color
                       statusbarView.tintColor = .white
                       view.addSubview(statusbarView)


                       statusbarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                       statusbarView.heightAnchor
                           .constraint(equalToConstant: statusBarHeight).isActive = true
                       statusbarView.widthAnchor
                           .constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
                       statusbarView.topAnchor
                           .constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
                       statusbarView.centerXAnchor
                           .constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

                   } else {
                       let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKeyPath: "statusBarWindow.statusBar") as? UIView
                       statusBar?.backgroundColor = color
                   }

                   UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = color
                   UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
                   UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
                   UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false

                   let navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: statusHieght, width: myScreen.size.width, height: 44))

                   //navBar.isTranslucent=true
                   //navBar.backgroundColor = .red
                   let navItem = UINavigationItem(title: "SomeTitle")
                   let doneItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.done, target:nil , action:#selector(ClickDone))
                   navItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneItem
                   navBar.setItems([navItem], animated: false)
                   self.view.addSubview(navBar)

                   let AllTopDistance=statusHieght+navBar.frame.size.height


                   let myView:UIView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: AllTopDistance, width: myScreen.size.width, height: myScreen.size.height-AllTopDistance))
                   myView.backgroundColor = .lightGray




                   myTableview=UITableView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: myScreen.size.width, height: myScreen.size.height-AllTopDistance))

                   myTableview.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellID)

                   print("\(statusHieght) \(myScreen.size.width) \(AllTopDistance)")
                   myTableview.delegate=self
                   myTableview.dataSource=self
                   //myTableview.backgroundColor=UIColor.red

                   myView.addSubview(myTableview)

                   self.view.addSubview(myView)

    }

    @objc func ClickDone(){
               print("Done")
           }

    @objc func DownloadFiles(Filename : String , getIndexPath : IndexPath){

        url = URL(string: "http://49.xx.xx.xx/TestDownload/\(Filename)")!
        DestFolder = "JPG"
        print("download \(String(describing: url))")

                   let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "com.example.DownloadTaskExample.background")

                    let session = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue())


                       let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
                       let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
                       let docURL = URL(string: documentsDirectory)!

                       let downloadsPath = docURL.appendingPathComponent(DestFolder!)


                       if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: downloadsPath.absoluteString) {
                           do {
                               try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: downloadsPath.absoluteString, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                           } catch {
                               print(error.localizedDescription);
                           }
                       }

                       let prevFile =  downloadsPath.appendingPathComponent(url!.lastPathComponent)


                       if FileManager().fileExists(atPath: prevFile.path) {

                           debugPrint("The file already exists at path, deleting and replacing with latest \(prevFile.path)")
                           //print(prevFile)

                           if FileManager().isDeletableFile(atPath: prevFile.path){
                               do{
                                   try FileManager().removeItem(atPath: prevFile.path)

                                   debugPrint("previous file deleted \(prevFile.path)")
                                   let task = session.downloadTask(with: url!)
                                   task.resume()

                               }catch{
                                   debugPrint("current file could not be deleted \(prevFile.path)")
                               }
                           }
                       // download the data from your url
                       }else{


                            let task = session.downloadTask(with: url!)
                            task.resume()
                       }

    }

}

extension ViewController: URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDownloadDelegate, URLSessionTaskDelegate
{



    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {

        if totalBytesExpectedToWrite > 0 {
            let downloadProgress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)

            print("\(downloadProgress)")


            print("\(downloadTasks[downloadTask])")

            guard let indexPath = downloadTasks[downloadTask] else { return }
            let myViewTag = viewTag(for: indexPath)

            guard let progressBar = self.view.viewWithTag(myViewTag) as? UIProgressView else { return }

                   //let tableIndex = NSIndexPath(row: uploadTasks[task]!.row, section: 0)


                   DispatchQueue.main.async {

                       progressBar.progress = downloadProgress
                       if(downloadProgress==1)


                       {
                           progressBar.removeFromSuperview()
                           let indexPosition = IndexPath(row: self.downloadTasks[downloadTask]!.row, section: 0)
                           self.dataArrDone.replaceObject(at: self.downloadTasks[downloadTask]!.row, with: "Done")
                           self.myTableview.reloadRows(at: [indexPosition], with: .none)

                       }
                   }
        }

    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {



            let documentsUrl = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)

                   // your destination file url
            let destination = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("\(DestFolder!)/\(url!.lastPathComponent)")
            let responseStatusCode = (downloadTask.response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode


             debugPrint("Download finished: \(location) to \(destination) code \(responseStatusCode)")

            if(responseStatusCode==200)
            {

                do{
                   try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: destination)
                    debugPrint("new file saved")

                    } catch {
                        debugPrint("file could not be saved")
                    }
            }

         }


}


extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{

            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
               return dataArr.count
           }

            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

                  let hCell:CGFloat = 50.0

                  return hCell
              }

           func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = myTableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath)


               let customKeys=["type","Facebook","Google","Twitter"];
               let customsValues=["uploadFile","Mark","Lary","Goo"];
               let customDatas=Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(customKeys,customsValues))




            //uploadImage(data_dict: customDatas, indexPath : IndexPath)
            let Done : NSString = dataArrDone[indexPath.row] as! NSString
            if(Done .isEqual(to: "wait"))
                {
                    let progressView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 10, width: 100, height: 20))
                  progressView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

                  let progressBar = UIProgressView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 5, width: 100, height: 20))
                  progressBar.tag=viewTag(for: indexPath)
                  progressBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
                  progressView.addSubview(progressBar)

                  cell.addSubview(progressView)

                    DownloadFiles(Filename: dataArr[indexPath.row] as! String, getIndexPath: indexPath)

            }else{
                //progressView.removeFromSuperview()
                let doneText: UILabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
               doneText.textColor=UIColor.black
               doneText.backgroundColor=UIColor.green
               doneText.text="Done"
               doneText.font=UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
               cell.addSubview(doneText)
            }

               return cell
           }

}
```

after run application all method working.
but progressview in uitableview cell not update download progress.

how to fix it.

Thank you

Comment: Use post notification from URL session delegate method & observe this notification on Cell & based on notification value, change progress bar value

Comment: can u example??